# include css counters in anchor links?

Tags: css, markdown, jekyll, css-counter

## Problem summary

I'm creating a print stylesheet for a simple html document with id-referenced headers and anchors to reference these headers, like

```
<h1 id="the-document">The Document</h1>
<h2 id="background">Background</h2>
<h2 id="implementation">Implementation</h2>
<p>For details, see <a href="#background">Background</a>.</p>
```

The print styles need section numbers that are created with css counters like

```
h1 {
  counter-reset: section
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(section) ". ";
  counter-increment: section
}
```

I try to add the "1. " that is prepended to the "Background" section also to the anchor that references the section, i.e. the result should look like

> ## The Document
>
> ### 1. Background
>
> ### 2. Implementation
>
> For details, see [1. Background](//)

**Is there a way to add the counter of the section that is referenced to the anchor that references the section?** Without JavaScript?

## What I've tried

Adding the current counter to all references results in the wrong counter value, like

```
a[href^=#]:before { content: counter(section) ". "; }
```

would result in

> For details, see [2. Background](//)

I know this could be done with JavaScript:

```js
let section = 0;
const h2s = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2')).reduce((h2s, h, i) => {
  switch (h.nodeName) {
    case 'H1': section = 0; break;
    case 'H2': h2s[h.id] = ++section; break;
  }
  
  return h2s;
}, {})

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]')).forEach(_ => _.textContent = `${h2s[_.href.split('#')[1]]}. ${_.textContent}`)
```

```css
h1 {
  counter-reset: section;
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(section) ". ";
  counter-increment: section;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="the-document">The Document</h1>
<h2 id="background">Background</h2>
<h2 id="implementation">Implementation</h2>
<p>For details, see <a href="#background">Background</a></p>
```

Whom it may concern, I'm authoring markdown in Jekyll (for a GitHub Page, so no plugins) and would rather drop the feature than add JavaScript to implement it.

Comment: I doubt you will find a CSS only solution. This seems to be a lot of job for CSS especially if you want something geneic (we can only find few hack for some particular cases)